# Performing a join on ZenCart's address book entries

Tags: php, mysql, join, zen-cart

I have the following bits of code:

```
$referrers_query = 
select c.customers_id, c.customers_firstname, c.customers_lastname, 
c.customers_email_address, c.customers_telephone, a.entry_street_address, 
a.entry_city, a.entry_state, a.entry_country_id, n.countries_name, 
a.entry_zone_id, a.entry_postcode, r.referrer_customers_id, 
r.referrer_key, r.referrer_homepage, r.referrer_approved, 
r.referrer_banned, r.referrer_commission from  customers as c,  
address_book  as a, referrers  as r, countries as n  
where a.entry_country_id = n.countries_id and c.customers_id = r.referrer_customers_id 
and a.address_book_id = c.customers_default_address_id  order by c.customers_lastname;
```

What I would like to do, is instead of making a `WHERE` clause join, I'd like to nest the joins.

There are five database tables noted above.
customers, address_book, referrers, countries, zones.

But I have no idea where to get started. The main problem with this is using the above statement, I seem to lose a few records from the select. This is because some records are using a 'zone_id' = 0. A fix to this was to simply create a blank record for 0 but besides that, can I use a join to fix this?

Comment: Maybe reformat that query so it's actually readable? Maybe indicate which is line 502? Maybe try `var_dump()` instead of `echo`?

Comment: changed the entire question altogether but I will attempt the var_dump method as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query written with explicit `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT c.customers_id, c.customers_firstname, c.customers_lastname, 
    c.customers_email_address, c.customers_telephone, a.entry_street_address, 
    a.entry_city, a.entry_state, a.entry_country_id, n.countries_name, 
    a.entry_zone_id, a.entry_postcode, r.referrer_customers_id, 
    r.referrer_key, r.referrer_homepage, r.referrer_approved, 
    r.referrer_banned, r.referrer_commission
FROM customers AS c
    JOIN referrers AS r ON (c.customers_id = r.referrer_customers_id)
    JOIN address_book AS a ON (a.address_book_id = c.customers_default_address_id)
    JOIN countries AS n ON (a.entry_country_id = n.countries_id)
ORDER BY c.customers_lastname
```

If you want to also get the info from the zones table if a match exists, you would need to add a `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT c.customers_id, c.customers_firstname, c.customers_lastname, 
    c.customers_email_address, c.customers_telephone, a.entry_street_address, 
    a.entry_city, a.entry_state, a.entry_country_id, n.countries_name, 
    a.entry_zone_id, a.entry_postcode, r.referrer_customers_id, 
    r.referrer_key, r.referrer_homepage, r.referrer_approved, 
    r.referrer_banned, r.referrer_commission
FROM customers AS c
    JOIN referrers AS r ON (c.customers_id = r.referrer_customers_id)
    JOIN address_book AS a ON (a.address_book_id = c.customers_default_address_id)
    JOIN countries AS n ON (a.entry_country_id = n.countries_id)
    LEFT JOIN {zones table name} AS z ON (z.{zones id column name} = a.entry_zone_id)
ORDER BY c.customers_lastname
```

and also add the columns you want to select to the top of the query.  A `LEFT JOIN` always returns a result from the left table (first one listed) and if there is no match in the right table, it returns `NULL`s for the right table's columns.

Comment: Thank you so much. The table name for the zones was actually zones and the column for the ID is zone_id but I managed to figure that. This works perfectly.